# finding an illegal node in a binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I want to find a node - v,  in a binary search tree which meets one (and only one) of the following the conditions:

- v's left subtree includes at least one value that is smaller than v
- v's right subtree includes at least one value that is bigger than v

I know that exactly one node v exists in my tree - T, and i would like to find it.

I thought of this algorithm, given a tree T :

1. Check if T's left son is bigger then the root, or if T's right son is smaller then the root, if one of these conditions are true - return the root.
2. Else, check recursivly T's right and left subtrees, assuming they exist. If both of them don't exist  it means we reached a leaf and return -1 (shouldn't happen)

So my first question is: is the algorithm correct? does it do what it's suppose to?
Second, I need it to be in time complexity of `O(n)` is this happening?

If i'm wrong i would love to get a valid algorithm for that problem

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem clearly defined. If you can try to clean up your wording on what you are trying to do, than someone might be able to provide you with a correct solution. As Sneftel pointed out, your solution doesn't work either... so you might want to clean that up in your question as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement an algorithm quite literally, by translating the condition into code:

```
boolean hasValueSmallerThan(Vertex startFrom, int value) {
    return
        this.value < value
    ||  (startFrom.left != null && hasValueSmallerThan(startFrom.left, value))
    ||  (startFrom.right != null && hasValueSmallerThan(startFrom.right, value));
}
boolean hasValueGreaterThan(Vertex startFrom, int value) {
    return
        this.value > value
    ||  (startFrom.left != null && hasValueGreaterThan(startFrom.left, value))
    ||  (startFrom.right != null && hasValueGreaterThan(startFrom.right, value));
}
Vertex findInvalid(Vertex startFrom) {
    if (startFrom.left == null && startFrom.right == null) {
        return null;
    }
    // v's right subtree includes at least one value that is bigger than v
    if (startFrom.left == null) {
        boolean checkRight = hasValueGreaterThan(startFrom.right, this.value);
        return (checkRight) ? this : findInvalid(startFrom.right);
    }
    // v's left subtree includes at least one value that is smaller than v
    if (startFrom.right == null) {
          boolean checkLeft = hasValueSmallerThan(startFrom.left, this.value);
          return (checkLeft) ? this : findInvalid(startFrom.left);
    }
    // If we are here, both subrtees are non-null
    boolean leftIsInvalid = hasValueSmallerThan(startFrom.left, this.value);
    boolean rightIsInvalid = hasValueGreaterThan(startFrom.right, this.value);
    // Return XOR of the two checks, which means "one of the two is true, but not both"
    if (leftIsInvalid ^ rightIsInvalid) {
        return this;
    }
    Vertex leftFind = findInvalid(startFrom.left);
    if (leftFind != null) return leftFind;
    return findInvalid(startFrom.right);
}
```

This implementation is very straightforward: it has two recursive helpers, `hasValueSmallerThan` and `hasValueGreaterThan`, which are used by the recursive `findInvalid`.

Most of the code there deals with situations when one of the two subtrees is empty. Other than that's it's a straightforward translation of the requirements into code.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm does not do what it's supposed to. Consider the following tree:

```
       3
      / \
     2   5
    / \
   1   4
```

No node has a child which violates the ordering, but the left subtree of the root contains a value which is larger than the root.

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer Try this: recursively find the largest/smallest (left/right child) node in each subtree. Compare them to the root node of the tree. If it's smaller/larger than the root, rebuild that tree.